# Arduino Wireless SD Shield

Tags: arduino-leonardo, sd-card, wireless

Is it possible to use the Wireless SD shield without the wireless function, or XBEE Module? I do not need it to be wireless it simply was cheaper than any other I could find, so I was wondering if it was possible to use it just like a normal, non-wireless SD Shield? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, on a combined "Something plus SD card" shield like this the SD card is a completely separate section to the rest of it. The only real exception is on some audio shields (mp3) where the SD card is directly controlled by the audio CODEC chip.

So yes, you can pick and choose which portions of the shield you actually use in your code. Just by not using the bits you don't want to use.